# generate pb files from caffe trained model

Tags: caffe

I want to run a trained caffe model in android. I was planning to use the [AICamera](https://github.com/caffe2/AICamera) example by caffe and then modify it to run my model. I was able to compile and build the project.

Currently i have the caffe model definition as a `prototxt` file and the pretrained model as a `.caffemodel` file. But the AICamera is using `squeeze_init_net.pb` file and `squeeze_predict_net.pb` file for reading models. So how can i convert the files i have to .pb files?

Answer (score 0):

The AICamera sample that you linked is for Caffe2, which is not backward compatible with Caffe.

In [Caffe2 Model Zoo](https://caffe2.ai/docs/zoo.html) page they talk about it:

> Compatibility:
>   Caffe2 utilizes a newer format, usually found in the
>   protobuf .pb file format, so original .caffemodel files will require
>   conversion.

In the same page, they link to the [Migration page](https://caffe2.ai/docs/caffe-migration.html) where they explain how to convert the older .caffemodel to the .pb file format.

Basically, they provide a [python script](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/caffe2/python/caffe_translator.py) to convert your old format to the newer one. Also, there is a [test script](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/caffe2/python/caffe_translator_test.py).

If you want to run your .caffemodel, there are 2 ways (that I know of):

1. Convert it to the newer .pb file format
2. Load your .caffemodel with the help of [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d6c/tutorial_dnn_android.html)